# Copy email from iPhone

Tags: ios, email, password, iphone

What I ask here is a completely LEGIT operation. I have my best friend(passed away)'s iPhone 4s. i have the complete authority to complete all following operations in his name because it is in their will.

I have backup almost all from iOS, like : Call Logs, Contacts, Messages, Notes, Photos, Photos Martin, Voice Messages, Web History. It's DONE with phoneview...

What I dont have access to is the hotmail mail on their phone. The phone has 2 hotmail accounts, with email working perfectly fine, but I dont have the password of this account.

How would I take a copy of all the hotmail info from the phone to and access it on the computer. Do you know a software that can do this?

NOTE : It's becoming more and more rush as I will have to get the phone back to the company.... please any idea ?

--

How can i "see" what is the working password used in the hotmail account on the iPhone, so I can login on a desktop computer?

--

temp solution : create a gmail account, and manually transfer all 5000+ email to the gmail account. i will have it all, after 10-15 hours work !

Comment: You'll need to talk to the email provider about access to his email account.

Comment: I know that i can ASK hotmail (microsoft) to get a copy of the account, but contacting microsoft is harder that calling God... i use that as a last choice and if i have hourssss to looooose !

Answer (score 1):

Sounds strange, but why not use the "Forgot Password" option at Login with a browser => so you do not need to contact God ;-) bue a robot answers your request fairly immediate.

Mail goes into the Mail account on the handy - so you can change it and have it.
Else - there is no way to read the key-store .. this is where the pw is stored in the handy.

Comment: cannon answer security question. telephone number link to a phone he no longer have like 5 years ago, and i have to give 2 old email password witch i dont know...